How to see code differences regarding PHP versions in PhpStorm?
I expect to mark PhpStorm code differences with reference to lower PHP versions, but PhpStorm is not marking anything. I developed a code in PHP 8.2 and expect to see, what I have to change in code after downgrading to PHP version 7.2

Now, I changed to PHP 7.2, but PhpStorm doesn't care. I expect to mark, for instance private EntityRepository $productRepository;, but PhpStorm doesn't mark it. What should I do?


What's the reason for downgrading, PHP7.2 had its end of life ~3,5 years ago.

I don't understand why you'd expect private EntityRepository $productRepository to be marked (as an error I assume?) under PHP 7.2. You also seem to have removed that line completely (or it's cropped out the 2nd image)

@apokryfos Typed properties were introduced in PHP/7.4.

It should be automatic. You must have some problem with your PhpStorm installation or project metadata. Try "File/ Repair IDE".

Got issue by my own. I had to reactivate PHP errors

